# Facebook API: Get people list who like a page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to get all people list who liked our page using Facebook API? I looked at the documentation but i am not able to find that.

Can any one help me out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: There is no endpoint for that in the Graph API. You can get some breakdowns via the Page Insights, but not the actual people which like your Page.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/insights
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/insights#page_users